# html to cshtml - unexplained page shifting

Tags: html, razor

Built a web-page using atom. Then, copy and pasted code into an cshtml file for an ASP .NET web project.

Almost everything shifts. Fonts, buttons, images, and page header shrink in size.

cshtml file's width measures different than the original html file (~300px difference) but I am using the exact same code.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? It's as if there is an extra 300px in my view when using cshtml.

references:

html
[image: html]

cshtml
[image: cshtml]

Github links for my code:

ASP .NET (one with issues) => https://github.com/thomasbaldwin222/WestfaliaHosting

HTML => https://github.com/thomasbaldwin222/Westfalia

Comment: looks like there is conflict of css can you please update which css and resources you add in both projects? also the check the order of css must be same as in html !

Comment: Use your browser's Web Inspector (F12) tools on an element that looks different and see where its font-size property is being inherited from. My guess is that you have a `_Layout.cshtml` file that's being used that references a `.css` file that sets `body { font-size: smaller; }` or something.

Comment: I didn't see anything. I've also uploaded links to the two projects. The logo, for example, is the same dimensions in each project. I think for some reason the razor view has an extra 300px in it's width...